# Rails 3.1 - How do I organize multiple index actions for the same model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

I have a User model that has_many projects. The Project model belongs_to the User model. I am currently using the projects_controller.rb index action to display all of the projects that have been created across all users (Project.all).

On a separate page, I would also like a way to display all of the projects that belong to a specific user (i.e. go to page and be able to see all of the projects that belong to a given user).

I am having difficulty figuring out which controller/action/view to use and how to set up the routes because I am already used the index action for the projects_controller for the purpose of displaying all of the projects.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do /users/{:id}/projects, which would map to the users controller projects action. The route would have to be custom member action

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get 'projects'
  end
end
```

Comment: this seems like the most straight forward solution. Alot of great answers though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

rather than having different pages of listing. use same index page based on different criterias i.e. filters.

**URL**

```
match ":filter/projects", :to => "projects#index"
```

**inside controller something like**

```
case params[:filter]
when "all"
  @projects = Project.all
when "user" 
  @projects = current_user.projects
when "batch"
  # ..
else
  # ..
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you display the projects that belong to a particular user on the `User#show` page?

Something like this perhaps:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # rest of class omitted...
```

Then you can access the projects that belong to the user in the view for the show page by calling `@user.projects`.

Answer (score 0):

You should nest `projects` under `users` to get working code/paths like: `/users/1/projects` without any additional coding, so you need to change your resource lines in `routes.rb` to:

```
resources :users, :shallow => true do 
  resources :projects
end
```

and then under Projects#show action instead of `Project.find(params[:id])` you need to get `Project.find(params[:user_id])`

That's seems to be correct

Comment: would this make the /projects route that I am using to display all projects no longer valid?