# Multiple index actions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, controller

I have a `Game` model and `GamesController`. Currently my `index` page shows first 10 records from the database for the purpose of the application. However, i want to make another page where all of the games are being shown.

My question is, what's *the Rails way™* of achieving this purpose? Is it possible to have the `index` action of my `GamesController` to make requests based on what URL i want to render? (Something like `http:localhost:3000/all`)

[Rails 3.1 - How do I organize multiple index actions for the same model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641018/rails-3-1-how-do-i-organize-multiple-index-actions-for-the-same-model/)
was the closest to my issue, but the question tackles problem from rails 3.1 dating back to 2012.

Comment: You can use `Request.url` to check which url been called. Though I will recommend to use different actions for these two actions.

Comment: @Зелёный Have you read my question? I've seen this problem but mine has a different nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really only have one index action per controller, but there are a couple of ways you can achieve this.

First, simply create a new action and have a separate page. Think of an appropriate name for it and create the controller, route, and view. You can keep the amount of code to a minimum by having much of the view code in a partial and use that in both views.

The other way to do this, if you really only want one action, is to pass a parameter to the index controller and query the database based on that parameter. For instance:

```
link_to 'link text', game_index_path(:g => 'all')
```

will create a url like: http://domain.com/game/index?g='all' and in the controller you can do this:

```
def index
   which_games = params[:g] # should be all in this case
   @games = Game.where(:criteria => which_games)
end
```

You can use this same method to implement sorting and filtering and all sorts of things.

Comment: Fantastic, exactly the answer i've been looking for. I was unsure whether it's a good practice to create a completly new action outside the standard ones (in this case i simply named my action "all" and creared particular views and routes)